# How to change colour of an element when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

How the page works: 
A user completes the registration form (name, surname, age ...).
The admin can see all these values and either approve or reject each one of them by clicking the corresponding radio button.

What I want: 
In my .phtml file I have a loop that produces different groups of radio buttons (1 group for name field, 1 group for surname, etc.).
Each radio button has a different ID. 
Each radio button group corresponds to a different element in the page(name, surname ...). 
How can I check which one of the 2 radio buttons per group is checked, and change the background colour of it's corresponding element (name, surname ...)?

What I have done so far: 
The only way I could make it works is by actually clicking the radio button and getting it's ID. Then by using the 'data-html' directive I change the colour of the corresponding field. 
I have tried changing the .click function to .checked but I could not figure out how to get the IDs I need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radio-approved').click(function(){
        greenColor($(this));
    });

    $('.radio-rejected').click(function(){
        redColor($(this));
    });
});

function greenColor(button) {

    var correspondingField=document.getElementById(button.data('html'));

    $(correspondingField).css({
        "background-color": "green"
    });
}

function redColor(button) {

    var correspondingField=document.getElementById(button.data('html'));

    $(correspondingField).css({
        "background-color": "red"
    });
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use CSS to set background color for specific class?

Comment: first off, since you're using jquery, you don't need to use pure js methods `getElementById()`

Comment: @ygorbunkov why not? I often mix the two as some native js things are just faster and more efficient than it's jquery alternative - just because you use jQuery doesn't mean you should ignore native js if it is better in certain circumstances (granted here it seems to be wasted)

Comment: @user1597430 Hmm, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: @Ranga the classic way is to create CSS style for a specific class and use JS only to add or remove a class from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```js
$('[type="radio"][name="status"]').on('change', event => {
  $(event.target).closest('tr').css('background-color', $(event.target).val() == 'approve' ? 'green' : 'red')
});
```

```css
td {width:150px;text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Kevin</td><td>Spacey</td><td><input type="radio" value="approve" name="status">approve</input><input type="radio" value="reject" name="status">reject</input></td>
    </tr>
      <td>Nicolas</td><td>Cage</td><td><input type="radio" value="approve" name="status">approve</input><input type="radio" value="reject" name="status">reject</input></td>
    </tr>
      <td>Robert</td><td>Downey</td><td><input type="radio" value="approve" name="status">approve</input><input type="radio" value="reject" name="status">reject</input></td>
    </tr>
      <td>Chris</td><td>Evans</td><td><input type="radio" value="approve" name="status">approve</input><input type="radio" value="reject" name="status">reject</input></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```